# jQuery - Display DIV on Hover, when parent DIV class is used multiple times

Tags: jquery, class, hover, mouseover

Not sure how to fix this problem - I am using jQuery to show a div when another div is hovered over, however I am using the same div class multiple times on the page.

Here is my code:

```
$(".map-item, .map-item-trail").live("mouseenter", function() {
 $(".mapitem-smalldescription").fadeIn("normal", function() {  
  });
});
```

The class "map-item" and "map-item-trail" is used many times, so when you hover over one, is shows the popup div on ALL of them.  How can I alter the code so the popup only appears on the item thats being hovered over.

Thanks
Zach

Comment: Is there a one-to-one relationship between the two?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the live method?

Comment: @Trevor That's not unreasonable, if, for example, HTML is dynamically being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only fade in the elements that can be found in the element that is being hovered over.

```
$(".map-item, .map-item-trail").live("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).find(".mapitem-smalldescription").fadeIn("normal", function() {  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your html mark-up it's difficult to advise specifically, but assuming the third `.mapitem-smalldescription` relates the to the third `.map-item` or `.map-item-trail`, this *should* work:

```
$(".map-item, .map-item-trail").live("mouseenter", function() {
    var itemIndex = $(this).index();
    $(".mapitem-smalldescription:eq(" + itemIndex + ")").fadeIn("normal", function() {  
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define the same id for each item pair and do something like:

```
$(".map-item, .map-item-trail").live("mouseenter", function() {
 $(".mapitem-smalldescription[mapitem="+this.id+"]").fadeIn("normal", function() {  
  });
});

<div class="map-item" id="1"></div>
<div class="map-item" id="2"></div>
<div class="mapitem-smalldescription" mapitem="1"></div>
<div class="mapitem-smalldescription" mapitem="2"></div>
```

---

An other solution is to put your smalldescription div just after its div element and use next():

```
$(".map-item, .map-item-trail").live("mouseenter", function() {
 $(this).next().fadeIn("normal", function() {  
  });
});
```

Comment: No, you can't. An `id` has to be *unique* in the document, otherwise it's invalid mark-up and introduces inconsistencies. It's also worth noting that an `id`, outside of an HTML5 doctype document, would also be invalid.

Comment: @David An ID is invalid outside of an HTML5 document? You meant a numeric ID, right?

Comment: @Nyuszika: I did, yeah :) +1 for the catch..!